# Using embedded standard HTML forms with ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, html, forms

I have a standard aspx page with which I need to add another standard HTML form into and have it submit to another location (external site), however whenever I press the submit button the page seems to do a post back rather than using the sub-forms action url.

A mock up of what the form relationships is below. Note in the real deployment the form will be part of a content area of a master page layout, so the form needs to submit independantly from the master page form.

```
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
       <head runat="server">
          <title>Untitled Page</title>
       </head>
       <body>
           <form id="form1" runat="server">
           <div>
               <form id="subscribe_form" method="post" action="https://someothersite.com" name="em_subscribe_form" > 
                    <input type="text" id="field1" name="field1" />
                    <input id="submitsubform" type="submit" value="Submit" />
               </form>
           </div>
           </form>
       </body>
   </html>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's an interesting problem.  Ideally you only want the 1 form tag on the page as other users have mentioned.  Potentially you could post the data via javascript without having 2 form tags.

Example taken from [here](http://mentaljetsam.wordpress.com/2008/06/02/using-javascript-to-post-data-between-pages/), modified for your needs.  Not 100% sure if this will work for you but I think this is how you'll have to approach it.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head runat="server">
<title>Untitled Page</title>
<script type="text/javascript">

function postdata()
{
   var fieldValue = document.getElementById("field1").value;
   postwith("http://someothersite.com",{field1:fieldValue});
}

function postwith (to,p) {
  var myForm = document.createElement("form");
  myForm.method="post" ;
  myForm.action = to ;
  for (var k in p) {
    var myInput = document.createElement("input") ;
    myInput.setAttribute("name", k) ;
    myInput.setAttribute("value", p[k]);
    myForm.appendChild(myInput) ;
  }
  document.body.appendChild(myForm) ;
  myForm.submit() ;
  document.body.removeChild(myForm) ;
}

</script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
           <div>
                <input type="text" id="field1" name="field1" />
                <asp:Button ID="btnSubmitSubscribe" runat="server" Text="Submit" OnClientClick="postdata(); return false;" />

       </div>

</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

If javascript is not a viable option  - you can use .Net's HttpWebRequest object to create the post call in code behind.  Would look something like this in the code behind (assuming your text field is an asp textbox:

```
private void OnSubscribeClick(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
string field1 = Field1.Text;


ASCIIEncoding encoding=new ASCIIEncoding();
string postData="field1="+field1 ;
byte[]  data = encoding.GetBytes(postData);

// Prepare web request...
HttpWebRequest myRequest =
  (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://someotherwebsite/");
myRequest.Method = "POST";
myRequest.ContentType="application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
myRequest.ContentLength = data.Length;
Stream newStream=myRequest.GetRequestStream();
// Send the data.
newStream.Write(data,0,data.Length);
newStream.Close();
}
```

Comment: added a javascript-less method as well

Comment: Ah, nice. I knew there was a way to do it from code-behind. Thanks.

Comment: @brendan Does this work if the user submits the form with the Enter Key?

Answer (score 7):

If you add an ASP.NET button to the form, and set its PostBackUrl property to the external site, then all the form data will be posted to that URL.

Comment: That did it. I used this technique to post a form from a DNN HTML module.

Comment: This, for me, is by far the simplest and neatest solution.

Comment: Brilliant! This does not break anything that I can tell. Good Job!!

Answer (score 6):

There is a very nice tricky solution for this problem.

You can insert a `</form>` tag before your `<form>` to close the asp.net form which causes the problem. Do not forget to add a `<form>` tag after your html form. It may cause the editor to give you an exception, but do not worry, it will work.

Comment: Good Job breaking layout in iE8

Comment: Breaks layout in IE9 as well, this is not a good general solution.

Answer (score 3):

Nested forms are not possible in HTML [according to the W3C](http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/html3/forms.html).  You can achieve your intended result using JavaScript or [with jQuery](http://blog.avirtualhome.com/2008/10/01/how-to-create-a-nested-form/) as explained by Peter on a blog called My Thoughts.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, Appetere Web Solutions has the best solution. Simple and elegant...and it's not a hack. Use the PostBackUrl.

I just tried it and everything works as expected.  I didn't want to use Javascript because I didn't want to include it in my Master Page for every page that uses it.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same situation as Ross - except that my input types were all of the "hidden" varitey.

Cowgod's answer got me thinking about nested forms within my .aspx page. I ended up "un-nesting" my 2nd form OUT of the main .aspx form (   ) and placed it (along with my js script tags) just under the body tag - but before the main .aspx form tag.

Suddenly, everything was submitting as it was supposed to.  Is this a hack?

Answer (score -1):

ASP.NET allows you to have multiple forms on one page, but only one can be `runat=server`. However I don't think you can nest forms at all.

You might have to make a new master page, one without a form tag on it so the form will work on that one page only. This is not a good solution, unless you can place the form outside the master pages' form, and use javascript to submit the second form, but that's hardly better. There really is no good solution for what you are trying to achieve, and if so I'd like to hear it. I don't think you can do a POST call from a code-behind, can you? I'm sure there's some way. But that's probably the only solution: from code.