# Is this normal asp.net webforms behaviour?

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I have a child page (using masterpages) where I want to include a regular (basic html form). When I look in the source of the page the  tags are stripped out. I know I can only have one , but does this include regular html forms, and if so, would it automatically strip them out?

Comment: its only <form runat="server"> that is limited to one... a normal <form> won't even be processed by the server but be seen as plain text

Comment: What do you mean the tags are stipped out?  The asp: ones?

Comment: I haven't tried two <asp> forms, but it is stripping out the normal <form> tags. I guess it is something someone else coded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the answer of Steven Cheng in this thread

http://bytes.com/topic/asp-net/answers/482951-form-runat-server-tag-masterpage-environment

Basically it seems that HTML itself does not support nesting of forms, that is what should be causing the problem, as your other forms are inside the form of Master Page. So you can try either cross-page posting as mentioned in the above thread or try the solutions mention here
[Using embedded standard HTML forms with ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588981/using-embedded-standard-html-forms-with-asp-net)

from W3.org

There can be several forms in a single document, but the FORM element can't be nested.

http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/html3/forms.html

Also when i checked the scenario with master page,  the nested form tag is there but it does not work, if i put the action of the nested form to other page, and try to post the nested form, it  posts to the page specified by the outer form (which is in master page).